# How to control multiple versions of ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I have written a .NET 4 NT service which connects to an Oracle 11g database and now I wish to deploy.

The target machine has Oracle drivers installed but only for ODP v2.  (I assume; there is only a 2.x folder in ODP.NET\Bin)

There is no upgrade path; company packages do not include what I am looking for, and I have no say in what should be included in those standard builds.

I am, on the other hand, permitted to install downloaded drivers ...

The target already runs 3 applications using the installed driver. It is a requirement that they continue to do so undisturbed.

So, with 2 sets of Oracle drivers installed, how do I ensure that my new application uses the new set whilst keeping the old set 'primary' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume both of the installers place the ODP assemblies in the GAC. If so, you can force use of a particular version.

Make sure you make a fully qualified reference in your .csproj files to the version of ODP you want to use. I don't know the specifics for the assemblies you need but here is an example of what the reference should look like in the csproj files. be sure it is Fully Qualified (has name, version, culture, publickey, architecture). And that SpecificVersion is true.

```
<Reference Include="ODP..., Version=4.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=theKey, processorArchitecture=...">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\ODP\ODP.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

Once compiled, this will make references in your compiled code to specific versions. At runtime, the assembly loader will look for the version you request. Use [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to trace that this is happening as expected. If not you can implement assembly binding redirect in various ways.

Take a look at these links if you need to go this route:

[Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx)

[How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at side-by-side deployment, [as outlined in Oracle's technetwork](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/moh-094755.html)

If this is impossible to do, for some reason, you will have to look at segregating the application or some other solution.

Comment: I have, so far, been unable to get any relevant information.  Your link doesnt seem to have any content either.